# Can't print to console in c++ eclipse kepler

Tags: c++

Running this code on windows using eclipse kepler

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

I've built it and run it with no errors, but I get nothing on the console. I've tried flushing the stream as well and that did not change anything.

Comment: This information alone is not sufficient, compiler options?

Comment: Are you sure you have a Console targeted application? Does the console pop up at all after running? I'd check the compiler options like Nooble said.

Comment: Look under `Run Configurations` for your program and check if the `Connect process input & output to a terminal` flag is set.

Comment: That flag is set. What kind of compiler options are you all looking for?

And yes, the console does popup but it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this is because Eclipse does not add `PATH` to `MINGW\bin` (if you use MinGW, of course). In the "Environment" tag, press "New", set it as:

```
"Name:PATH"
"Value:C:\MinGW\bin"
```

I have not enough info to be sure it's your answer, but try.